# storing the output of a function in a variable or serie in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to store the result of this function into a variable or a serie

```
def Main_Function ( df, table_of_limits):  
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in range(len(table_of_limits)):
            if     table_of_limits.iloc[j]['a'] < df.loc[i][j+2] < table_of_limits.iloc[j]['b'] :
                print('OK') 
               
            elif   table_of_limits.iloc[j]['c'] < df.loc[i][j+2] < table_of_limits.iloc[j]['d'] :
                print('Warning')
                
            else:
                print('Not_ok')
```

Comment: by 'result' do you mean the content of the print statements?

Answer (score 0):

You could return your print statement and store it in a variable. In general:

```
def foo (bar):
    return bar

returnValue = foo('some value')
```

In your case, if you are only interested in the values:

```
def Main_Function (df, table_of_limits):
    tmp = []  
    for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in range(len(table_of_limits)):
            if table_of_limits.iloc[j]['a'] < df.loc[i][j+2] < table_of_limits.iloc[j]['b']:
                tmp.append('OK')
               
            elif table_of_limits.iloc[j]['c'] < df.loc[i][j+2] < table_of_limits.iloc[j]['d'] :
                tmp.append('Warning')
                
            else:
                tmp.append('Not_ok')

    return tmp

someValue = Main_Function(df, table_of_limits)
```

If you are interested in keeping the individual index information, you could use a dataframe. A simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd

def foo (bar): 
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['i', 'j', 'result'])
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(2):
            tmp = tmp.append({'i': i, 'j': j, 'result': i+j}, ignore_index=True)
    return tmp

returnValue = foo('some value')
```